# Mapbox iOS Avoid Motorways / Highways

Tags: ios, mapbox, directions, mapbox-ios

The Mapbox web directions API supports avoiding motorways [Link](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/).

How is this done in the Mapbox iOS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mapbox Navigation SDK for iOS](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/) uses [`Direction`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/directions/0.30.0/Classes/Directions.html)s objects to provide directions between waypoints. You may provide a [`RouteOptions`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/directions/0.30.0/Classes/RouteOptions.html) object to each `Direction` to specify criteria for the results returned by the Mapbox Directions API. As noted in the changelog for the SDK [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions-swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0140), on the `RouteOptions` object there is a `roadClassesToAvoid` option where you can specify a `RoadClass` object to avoid, such as `motorway`. The source code for the `motorway` `RoadClass` can be found [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions-swift/blob/4d91bb2bd8332793500b72413d82de0fabe29809/Sources/MapboxDirections/RoadClasses.swift#L30), namely:

```
public static let motorway = RoadClasses(rawValue: 1 << 3)
```

The Nav SDK's [`NavigationRouteOptions`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/navigation/0.39.0/Classes/NavigationRouteOptions.html) extends `RouteOptions`. So, to calculate directions avoiding motorways in your iOS app, you should specify the `roadClassesToAvoid` option on a `NavigationRouteOptions` passed to `Directions.shared.calculate`. [This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/examples/basic/) for a basic navigation app is a great place to get started.